# How to use session in Laravel 5

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

I am trying to save some sessions variables but after return laravel does not save the session variable. Where is the problem in my code?

in web.php:

```
Route::get('/login', function(){
   return view(frontend.login);
 });
 Route::post('/login', function(Request $request){
   $control = "Some sql codes";
   if($control > 0){
       $user = "Some sql codes";
       $request->session()->start();
       $request->session()->put('user_id', $user->id);
       $request->session()->save();
       return view('frontend.logged_in);
   }
   else{
       return view('frontend.index);
   }
});
```

I know I should use controller but this is a temporary code and it should works fine here(am I right?). And when I do not use "return view('frontend.logged_in);" it saves the session variable but when I try to return it does not saves the session variable.

Note: If I choose 'file' for session driver theese codes are working just fine. But when I try to choose cookie codes doesn't work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is because of the line:

```
$request->session()->start();
```

You dont need to manually start the session, Laravel maintains the session for you.

Use following code instead:

```
if($control > 0){
   $user = "Some sql codes";
   session(['user_id'=>$user->id]);
   return view('frontend.logged_in);
}
```

See if that works for you.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the accept your answer. You were right, when learning phase reading documentation is very important! :)